# In WoW, how can I (via native features or add-ons) toggle between multiple spell bar configurations?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've set up (with BarTender4 and Elvui) a PVP action bar configuration like this, with the macros and spells configured the best way for my preferences, where I can cast 32 spells using the 1-12 number keys on my mouse with the addition of ctrl or alt, like so:

[image]

I love this, I want to keep it this way. But some of these spells are not good for raids, some could be removed, some added. The macros behind most of the spells (hence the duplicates here, some of the macros triggering the spells behave in different ways) are perfect for PVP but not for raids.

It would be awesome if there was a feature or an add-on that would let me toggle between different configurations depending on what Im about to do, like pressing a hotkey or button switches to a different set of spell / macros on the spell bars. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED

I've asked the lads over at the ElvUI discord. They say that since bar layouts are stored on Blizzard's end, ElvUI profiles might not be usable in this way. They recommend an addon like https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/action-bar-profiles which allows users to save custom action bar profiles, though not all of them seem to be fully updated.

---

> the below answer is not correct, but might help with the separation of the rest of the UI.

## OLD ANSWER

nearly every WoW addon has support for what's called "Profiles". Profiles allow you to configure distinct configurations and switch between them at will.

A [reddit post explains](https://www.reddit.com/r/WowUI/comments/7rk2s5/help_setting_up_actionbar_profiles_with_elvui/?st=juk6aztf&sh=42e5ffc2) how to do so:

> Type /ec to get into Elvui config.
>
> Click "profiles" in the left hand column. Look at what the name of your current profile is. Remember it.
>
> Now create a new profile. Name it Resto PvP (or whatever)
>
> Near the bottom is an option to copy the layout from another profile. Choose your original profile.
>
> Now you should have a new profile that's an exact duplicate of your old one. Adjust the spells/layouts/buttons on this PvP profile to your liking and you'll never have to set them again.
>
> When you want to PvE, choose the original profile. When you want to PvP, choose the PvP profile.

Note: since you're using Bartender, you'll probably have to use the Bartender profile page. This also doesn't switch talents automatically if you use different talents per content type, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asked, using bartender or ElvUI profiles will only move/change the location of the bars, but not the spells on the bars.

Comment: @Bash I see. I've asked the lads over at ElvUI Discord, they recommended an addon, but it might not be fully compatible with the current WoW version

Comment: Just had a look around, I think Action Bar Saver, Action bar profiles or Talent set Manager is what is required, you can set up hotbar configurations with /save restopvp and then load it with /load restopvp etc. Some of these may be discontinued so I will update this post once I find a recently updated (8.1+) addon which is currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a built-in solution in WoW, but it works only for one action bar (primary), so I'm not sure it actually helps you since you have used more than 12 buttons.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Mouse wheel up/down while hovering the cursor over the action bar will toggle it. However, it uses the space of other action bars and does not generate new bars out of thin air, so if you already used up your space this won't work properly.